# How to lock the form-size handles in the IDE's Form Designer?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

In the IDE's form designer, the main form's size-handles are not locked at design-time when clicking on **Edit -> Lock Controls**.

So how can I lock the form size handles in the IDE Designer?

Comment: Probably nobody answered this question until now because it only had a version specific tag, and that tag is very new. I added the generic delphi tag which should always be used alongside the version specific tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how can I lock the form size handles in the IDE Designer?

The rather simple (yet disappointing for you) answer is that the IDE has not such functionality.